# Correct syntax for inputing a String file into a 2D Array?

Tags: java, string, file-io, input, multidimensional-array

What is the correct syntax for creating a `2D array` from a text file?  This `array` must be `string` not `char` or `int`.  None of the information I've found on this is for `string`, and I haven't been able to figure the exact syntax out myself.

Comment: Also I'd like a `print` statement to go with this that maintains formatting of the `array`, so I can see what's going on inside.

Comment: You'll stay new if you don't try writing some.

Comment: You would need to know the number of rows before you instantiate the array as Java requires this.  As others have said, you could use an ArrayList (they grow more organically and do not require you to know the number of elements before you start adding to it) and if an array is later required, it has a method toArray to convert it to this.  In the array, if you have the current row number that you are reading (bearing in mind Java arrays are zero indexed i.e. start at 0 rather than 1) you could use the row number as the first parameter of your 2d array e.g. line[rowNum][0] = x

Comment: @ravi, I'm well aware of that, but nothing is gained by trying unguided alterations to similar code for hours on end.  (Trust me.  I've tried it.)

Comment: @Thefunkymonkey, *"You would need to know the number of rows before you instantiate the array as Java requires this."*  This is what I needed to know.  In that case (as I'm pretty sure I'll need a simple `array` later) I'll lockdown the number of rows in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ArrayList` object .Its internal implemetation is *Resizable or growable array*.
So you can achieve your requirement by `ArrayList<String>`.You can get even arry by using its utility methods.
For more details [ArrayList docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
For sample click [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/convert-arraylist-to-arrays-in-java/)

Comment: Yes, I knew/thought `arraylist` would make it open-ended, but I need to see how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Read2DimensionFileToList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
 String [][] sList=new String[100][2];
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String s;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));
int i=0;
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String []sArray=s.split(",");
                sList[i++][0]=sArray[0];
                sList[i][1]=sArray[1];
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a 2D `array`?

Comment: Either you can split it with "," or you split it first and put into 2D array.

Comment: This code does not create a 2D `array`.  It creates a `list`.  Apparently you're thinking by 2D I mean the file.  Rather, I mean the `array` that the file is loading into.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I've already figured it out, but seeing other ways of doing things is always good.